# Using Ubuntu distributions with a 2 in 1 laptop foldable tablet

Tags: compatibility

With these 2 in 1 laptop/Tablet can you dual boot Ubuntu distribution still with windows 10 Home?  If you can that is what I'm looking for.  I want to continue to use linux but just on a laptop/tablet 2 in 1.  Will I be able to use linux with the tablet that folds portion or just the laptop? That is my other related question.  What are the limitations with these laptop/tablet computers and linux?

Thanks

Comment: Also, with a different style laptop there is the touch screen laptop but no tablet.  The computer person at the store said Ubuntu recently should support a touch screen Ubuntu but not the Laptop/tablet with stylistic pen or hand writing without some stk files or special files to make it work.  Some I'm asking if Ubuntu works with a touch screen laptop? Thanks

Comment: Update your question with device model and hardware specs.

Comment: http://www.dell.com/us/p/inspiron-15-5559-laptop/pd?oc=fncwv2319h&model_id=inspiron-15-5559-laptop or http://www.dell.com/us/p/inspiron-15-5559-laptop/pd?oc=dncwv2371h&model_id=inspiron-15-5559-laptop

Comment: @user111 Hope [**this answer**](http://askubuntu.com/a/730380/497359) helps...    Welcome to AskUbuntu!, As you are new to AskUbuntu, One Suggestion: Please do not post same questions again and again.. that would be considered as Spam...