# Touch Screen Laptop Not Laptop/Tablet

Tags: compatibility

A computer person at a store said Ubuntu recently supports a touch screen Ubuntu but not the Laptop/tablet with stylistic pen or hand writing without some stk files or special files to make it work. I'm asking if Ubuntu works with a touch screen laptop? Thank you! Below are the two computers I'm looking at with all the specs on the page. Let me know if you need any additional information. Go Ubuntu!

Answer (score 0):

**Ubuntu works perfectly on a touch screen Laptop**, Yes! without any bugs.

I too have a touch screen laptop ( [Dell Inspiron 11 3147](http://www.dell.com/in/p/inspiron-11-3147-laptop/pd) ) which supports multi-touch features and gestures.

- The launcher moves up and down when you swipe on it either up or down
- The launcher icons also open when you single tap on them.
- Even the files and folders opens when double tapped on it.
- The minimize, maximize and the close button responds well on single tap.
- You can scroll the documents and web pages and many more.

You can get the basic touch features

## but..

Not **complete** features what you get on other operating systems (windows).

For example, If you want to **zoom** an image or a web page or a PDF document, doing it with two fingers won't work, i.e

- **Multi touch** etc..
- And also... I couldn't find a driver for my **Accelerometer** so.. it won't rotate your screen when you rotate your laptop.

So.. Lets hope for getting a better support for touch laptops in the next release of ubuntu i.e, 16.04

[image: 4 Modes of Dell Inspiron 3147]

Comment: Is there any update on this?